# Posted and getted data is not showing in app on restart of app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm using real time database for posting and getting of data in my app. 
Everything is fine but when I restart app, data is not showing in app.

Posted data is showing in database on restart but not showing on restart.

Here I'm posting data on database:

```
    Future<void> addTask(String newTaskTitle) async {
    final task = Task(title: newTaskTitle);
    const Url = ''// used url but hiding it here;
    await http.post(Url, body: json.encode({
      'title': task.title,
    }),);
    tasks.add(task);
    notifyListeners();
    }
```

Here I'm getting data from database:

```
    Future<void> fetchAndSetData() async {
    const Url = ''// used url but hiding it here;
    var response = await http.get(Url);
    final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    final List<Task> loadedTasks = [];
    extractedData.forEach((taskID, taskData) {
      loadedTasks.add(Task(
        id: taskID,
        title: taskData['title'],
      ));
    });
    tasks = loadedTasks;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: when you load the main Widget, call fetchAndSetData() in initState()

Comment: Now it worked with initState(), before i called with didChangeDependencies() so it was not working like this  :   var _isInit = false;
  void didChangeDependencies(){
    if(_isInit) {
      Provider.of<MainProvider>(context).fetchAndSetData();
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Comment: yep solved with initState, thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you render your app for the first time then call `fetchAndSetData()` in `initState()` function, with this the data that you stored in the database will be fetched before the actual rendering of widget tree.